# Is it reasonable to do Feature Engineering before Data Preprocessing?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I want to do data preprocessing with scikit learn and create a pipeline, among other things to avoid data leakage and streamline the process.
The problem though is that after fitting the data to the pipeline (which only includes preprocessing, no fitting the model!), the pipeline returns a numpy array.
This is fine if the pipeline includes a model at the end, cause you don't really get to "see" the processed data. But if you want to do feature engineering afterwards, it would be easier to get a data frame after fitting it to the preprocessing pipeline.

Since this seems difficult to accomplish because you would need all the (newly created) column names, to turn the array into a data frame,

I am wondering, whether it is reasonable to do the feature engineering *before* the preprocessing.

Comment: I don't really understand the issue, but in any case it may be useful to take a look at [featuretools](https://www.featuretools.com/) (their [git](https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools))

Comment: Scikit-learn does not assume data to come in Pandas DataFrames, Nympy arrays are just fine for it, so I can't see how this is an issue. It seems some kind of programming problem and as such, would be rather off-topic in here.

Comment: I don't think it's a programming issue at all.
I'm just asking whether it is reasonable to do feature engineering before preprocessing, since preprocessing with a scikit learn pipeline returns an array. This makes it more difficult to do feature engineering in my opinion.